# Login on java based from txt file

Tags: java, authentication, io, read-write

need help!, i have an assignment i need to make an login txt based, my program only read the first line

the txt look like this

```
Luthfi Luthfi Fitra
Fitra Fitra Khori
Khori Fitra Syifa
```

but it only read the first, so i could log in only using the top account 
here is my code

```
        public Login() {
    initComponents();
    txtPass.setText("");
}

public void Masuk(){
try {
String lokasi = "D:/settings.txt";
String username = txtUser.getText();
String password = txtPass.getText();


        FileReader fr = new FileReader(lokasi);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line,user,pass;
        boolean isLoginSuccess = false;
       while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
           user = line.split(" ")[1].toLowerCase();
    pass = line.split(" ")[2].toLowerCase();
           if (user.equals(username) && pass.equals(password)){
               isLoginSuccess = true;
               this.dispose();
               MainMenu mm = new MainMenu();
               mm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
               mm.setVisible(true);
               break;
           }
           else{
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "USERNAME/PASSWORD SALAH","WARNING!!",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
               break;
           }
       }
       fr.close();

}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
    }
        }
```

also why is everytime i insert the correct username and id it shows me that im succses but it show me the USERNAME/PASSWORD IS WRONG too

Comment: `user.equals(username)` you're comparing a lower case string to an unmodified (mixed case) string

Comment: im kinda new in this can you explain more ?, sorry

Comment: i just delete the toLowerString but it still giving me wrong password

Comment: @Luthfi Musafa check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problem in getting substring from file, change code like following snipet

```
        user = line.substring(0, 6).toLowerCase();
        pass = line.substring(7, 12).toLowerCase();
```

Update: Based on your comment , i am changing my solution

1) Change your file format like this

```
Luthfi Luthfi Hehe
Fitra Luthfi Khori
Syifa Khori Luthfi
Khori Syifa Luthfi
```

here first word in each line is user name and second word is password

2) Change your code like following

```
            user = line.split(" ")[1].toLowerCase();
            pass = line.split(" ")[2].toLowerCase();
```

3) if any username and password match, make login and break from while loop

Update again

```
package problems;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class FileRd {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            String lokasi = "D:/settings.txt";
            String username = txtUser.getText();
            String password = txtPass.getText();

            FileReader fr = new FileReader(lokasi);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line, user, pass;
            boolean isLoginSuccess = false;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                user = line.split(" ")[1].toLowerCase();
                pass = line.split(" ")[2].toLowerCase();
                if (user.equals(username) && pass.equals(password)) {
                    isLoginSuccess = true;
                    this.dispose();
                    MainMenu mm = new MainMenu();
                    mm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    mm.setVisible(true);
                    break;
                } 
            }
            if (!isLoginSuccess) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "USERNAME/PASSWORD WRONG", "WARNING!!", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
            fr.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```